# send multiple type of file and text with intent in Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-intent

I want to send a text and an excel file with the intent but no code I found works for me 
I tried it but only send file not text

```
      val uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context , "com.example.android.fogara2" , file)
    val sendIntent : Intent = Intent().apply {
        action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
        putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"hi")
        putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM , uri)
        type = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
        `package` = "com.whatsapp"
    }
        context.startActivity(sendIntent)
```

Comment: There is no requirement for `ACTION_SEND` implementations to support *both* `EXTRA_TEXT` *and* `EXTRA_STREAM`. You are welcome to offer both, but the developers of the other app can do what they want.

Comment: how then code would look like @CommonsWare

Comment: Other than perhaps adding `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` to the `Intent`, your code seems to be fine. Perhaps WhatsApp read [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/content/Intent#action_send) and decided to only support either `EXTRA_TEXT` or `EXTRA_STREAM` on any given `ACTION_SEND` `Intent`. That is their choice to make.

Comment: didn't work @CommonsWare